# Get the sequence with existing field in odoo 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I need to get the order number related with its service order. Each service order has many bench orders. E.g.: If the service order number is 223 the bench orders related to that are 223-1, 223-2, 223-3... if SO number is 553, bench order numbers must be 553-1, 553-2, 553-3, etc.

I tried it several ways and I failed to do it. Please help me. I used Odoo sequence to do that, but it did not give the output as I want. Here is my code: (E.g.: 223 means work authorization number).

```
class MyDepots_so(models.Model):
    _name = 'my_depots_so'

    so_parts_ids = fields.One2many('tiq_so_parts', 'so_p_id', string='Add Part Details', invisible='1')
    so_bo_ids  = fields.One2many('my_depots.so_bo', 
    so_work_authorization = fields.Integer("Work Authorization#")


class SO_Parts(models.Model):
    _name = 'tiq_so_parts'

    so_p_id = fields.Many2one('my_depots_so',string='Add Service Order Part', invisible='1')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        sequence     = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('so.benchorder') or '/'
        str_sequence = str(sequence)

        query = """SELECT so_work_authorization FROM my_depots_so WHERE id=%d """ % (so_p_id)
        self.env.cr.execute(query)
        result = self.env.cr.fetchall()
        result_number = json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)
        strip_number = result_number.strip('\' \" [] ')
        work_auth_no = str(strip_number)
        work_auth_no += "-"
        work_auth_no += str_sequence
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you are looking for something like this (I added a field to your `tiq_so_parts` model since you have to store the subsequence somewhere -where were you storing the *223-1*, *223-2*, *223-3*... values?
 I created the field `part_sequence` to store these values-).

```
class MyDepots_so(models.Model):
    _name = 'my_depots_so'

    so_parts_ids = fields.One2many('tiq_so_parts', 'so_p_id', string='Add Part Details', invisible='1')
    so_bo_ids = fields.One2many('my_depots.so_bo', 
    so_work_authorization = fields.Integer("Work Authorization#")


class SO_Parts(models.Model):
    _name = 'tiq_so_parts'

    so_p_id = fields.Many2one('my_depots_so',string='Add Service Order Part', invisible='1')
    part_sequence = fields.Char(string='Part Sequence')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        so_part = super(SO_Parts, self).create(vals)
        so_p_id = so_part.so_p_id
        main_sequence = so_p_id.so_work_authorization
        part_sequence = len(so_p_id.so_parts_ids)
        so_part.write({
            'part_sequence': str(main_sequence) + '-' + str(part_sequence),
        })
        return so_part
```